# Python OpenCV External Camera SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (ks.sys) error

Tags: python, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I want to use an external camera to capture video from OpenCV and display it in my GUI.When I plug in camera and execute my program , my computer shows a blue screen and SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (ks.sys) error , then restarts. Here is the code :

```
import Tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


width, height = 400, 300
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600+100+100")
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label()
lmain.pack(padx=100, pady=100)

def show_frame():
    if not cap.isOpened():             #checks for the opening of camera
        print("can't open the camera")
        flag, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    if flag is None:
        print "Major error!"
    elif flag:
        global last_frame
        last_frame = frame.copy()

pic = cv2.cvtColor(last_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
img = Image.fromarray(pic)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
lmain.imgtk = imgtk
lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
lmain.after(10, show_frame)


show_frame()
root.mainloop()
```

I used Logilink Usb 2.0 Video Grabber and I can capture video from 3rd party programs.But I can't capture in Python.I even tried another computer but same result.I use Anaconda - PyCharm..

Answer (score 0):

When does this Error occur? As I know, System_Service_Exception error is usually caused by incompatible software, hardware or driver and in most cases the best method is to look for the problematic driver, software or hardware, and disable it. In this case, you try disable Python External Camera , then check if the error appears.

I found a few solutions fix [this post](http://howtoinstallwindows10.com/system-service-exception-windows-10-fix/), maybe useful for you

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (ks.sys)

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (asmtxhci.sys)

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (dxgkrnl.sys)

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (win32kbase.sys)

Comment: It happenes when I just execute the program.When I use internal webcam it works.I use the official driver for the camera, and I can capture from it with 3rd party programs, but with python , it doesn't work.